# Isomorphism of orthogonal groups

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

> **1.5 Lemma.**
>   If $(V,b) \cong (V', b')$, then $\operatorname{O}(V,b) \cong \operatorname{O}(V',b')$.
>
> *Proof:*
>   If $\sigma \colon V \to V'$ is a bijective isometry, then $\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of the orthogonal groups.
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtUgM.png)

Since vector space are isomorphic there exist bijective isometry between those two vector space. I am confused whether $\tau$ is map from $V$ to $V$ or something else and how it become isomorphic.

Comment: The $\tau$ is an element of the corresponding orthogonal group. That is it's an invertible linear transformation $\tau:V\to V$ that preserves the bilinear form $b$

Comment: then how orthogonal group of V is isomorphic to V'?

Comment: The isomorphism is the map  $\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$

Comment: how to show it is injective or surjective given this as map?

Comment: There are a few things you'd need to show about the map: 1) that  $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$  is in the orthogonal group of V' 2) that it's a homomorphism 3) that it's bijective. Try these and get back to us

Comment: Ah sorry, my phone doesn't refresh comments. That's a better question

Comment: Injective is fairly easy note if  $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}=I$ then $\tau=\sigma^{-1} I \sigma$  apply this as a function to a vector in V and you'll see it's actually the identity of V

Comment: and what about surjectivity is it coming from rank nullity theorem?

Comment: So is your vector space finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes it is finite dimensional.

Comment: I don't think you need finite dimensional. I've answered your post below, sorry it took a while I had to proctor an exam and was away from my computer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text provides the explicit map of the isomorphism between the orthogonal groups namely

$$\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$$

There are 3 things you'd need to show to flesh out the details:

1. If $\tau$ in the orthogonal group of $V$ then   $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is in the orthogonal group $V'$
2. $\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is a homomorphism
3. $\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is bijective

You seemed most concerned about 3 in the comments so lets start with that.

---

**To SHOW 1)**

---

**$\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is injective**

Suppose that $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}=I$ where $I$ is the identity transformation of $V'$ then $\tau=\sigma^{-1}I\sigma$. Pick an arbitrary element $v \in V$ then

$$\begin{split}
\tau(v)&=(\sigma^{-1}I\sigma)(v)\\
&=\sigma^{-1}I(\sigma(v))\\
&=\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(v))\\
&=v\\
\end{split}$$
So $\tau$ is the identity transformation on $V$. Therefore the matp is injective.

---

**$\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is surjective**

Let $\alpha:V'\to V'$ be an invertible orthogonal transformation. Then consider $\tau:V \to V$ defined by $\tau=\sigma^{-1}\alpha\sigma$. It's clear that $\tau$ is invertible but we need to show it preserves the bilinear form $b$.

Note that $\sigma:V \to V'$ being a linear isometry means that for all $a,b \in V$

$$
b(a,b)=b'(\sigma(a),\sigma(b))
$$

and for all $x,y \in V'$

$$
b'(x,y)=b(\sigma^{-1}(a),\sigma^{-1}(b))
$$

Also note since $\alpha$ is in the orthogonal group of $V'$
$$
b'(\alpha (x),\alpha(y))=b'(x,y)
$$

So let $v,w \in V$ and consider 
$$\begin{split}
b(\tau(v),\tau(w))&=b(\sigma^{-1}\alpha\sigma(v),\sigma^{-1}\alpha\sigma(w)) \\
&=b(\sigma^{-1}(\alpha\sigma(v)),\sigma^{-1}(\alpha\sigma(w))) \\
&=b'(\alpha\sigma(v),\alpha\sigma(w))\\
&=b'(\sigma(v),\sigma(w))\\
&=b(v,w)\\
\end{split}
$$

So $\tau$ preserves the bilinear form $b$. Note that usually $\sigma$ is assumed to be linear. Often it is called a linear isometry. I don't think this is true or even 1) is true if $\sigma$ is not linear.

---

**To SHOW 2)**
$\alpha,\beta$ in the orthogonal group of $V$. Then 
$$
\sigma \alpha \beta \sigma^{-1}=(\sigma \alpha\sigma^{-1}) (\sigma\beta \sigma^{-1} )
$$

---

**To SHOW 1)**

Let $v,w \in V'$, tau in the orthogonal group of $V$

$$\begin{split}
b'(\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}(v),\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}(w)) 
&=b'(\sigma(\tau\sigma^{-1}(v)),\sigma(\tau\sigma^{-1}(w))) \\
&=b(\tau\sigma^{-1}(v),\tau\sigma^{-1}(w)) \\
&=b(\sigma^{-1}(v),\sigma^{-1}(w)) \\
&=b'(v,w)\\
\end{split}
$$

The linearity and invertibility of $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$ follow from $\sigma,\tau,\sigma^{-1}$ each being linear and invertible.